# 5 usable static IP addresses, can I have 5 computers each have their own WAN IP address when accessing Internet?

Tags: windows-7, ip, wan

With 5 static IP addresses, could I have 5 computers each get their own WAN IP or will all the computers share 1 WAN IP address? And if I want to setup 3 computers to use static IP #1 and 4 other computers to use the other 4 static IP, will that be possible or it'll be limited to 1 per computer?

Besides the cable modem/router, are there any other equipment I need?

If I upgrade to the 13 usable IP address package in a few months, typically would a provider give me a fresh batch of 13 usable IP or 8 in a different range?

Answer (score 3):

> With 5 static IP addresses, could I have 5 computers each get their own WAN IP or will all the computers share 1 WAN IP address?

You can have five machines that each have their own public IP address.

> And if I want to setup 3 computers to use static IP #1 and 4 other computers to use the other 4 static IP, will that be possible or it'll be limited to 1 per computer?

It usually is not that difficult to have one of the state IP addresses assigned to a router that that does NAT, allowing other devices with only private IP address to appear on the Internet with the router's public IP address.

> Besides the cable modem/router, are there any other equipment I need?

It depends on the capabilities of the router you have. If the router you have doesn't have that capability, you may want another router. You could also use the cable modem/router to interconnect the machines with the public IP address and connect that router to the WAN port of another router that NATs for the machines with only private IP addresses.

> If I upgrade to the 13 usable IP address package in a few months, typically would a provider give me a fresh batch of 13 usable IP or 8 in a different range?

They could do it either way, but most commonly they will renumber you into a new block.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick answer. I have a TP-LINK AC3200 router, I think it should be able to handle it. Do you know if I am able to choose when I could start using the static IPs? Like if I ordered them today and they assigned them to me the same day. Will my existing Internet on dynamic IP stop working immediately?

Comment: @NoNo That depends on your provider. They might continue to assign you a dynamic WAN IP and route your static IPs to that WAN IP.

Answer (score 2):

It would be EXTREMELY RARE to get "5 static IP addresses" - what you will most likely get is a /29 = a subnet of 8 IP addresses, however the first and last IP address of the range can't be used as they are special addresses (broadcast and network), and 1 IP address is assigned to the router, leaving 5 useable IP's.

The logic is similar with "13 IPs" - 16 ips, less broadcast, network and router IP = 13 addresses.

If the above is what you are getting, you need to clarify something with your provider - they will almost certainly provide these IP's to you over an additional IP outside this range, so the 5 static IP's will be on the LAN interface.     [If not, you will have a complex firewalling problem to solve (and, I'd argue, unless you have a switch with 5 routers hanging off it, or 5 devices each with there own firewall), configuring it would be  outside the scope of a Superuser]

Assuming the standard scenario, ie a subnet of 8 IP's routed to your router over an additional IP -

You would be able to set up computers to use more then 1 IP - unless they run Linux or equivalnet with complex routing (policy routing) this would really only be useful for incoming connections, as all connections initiated from the computer would prefer a particular connection.  You would want to use static IP addressing rather then DHCP.

The only equipment you will need is a router with firewall where you can turn off NAT.  Most consumer grade routers can be configured to do this - but you might want to get something which works with DD-WRT as the added functionality may help you later.

Only the provider could tell you if upgrading to 13 usable IP's would be possible in a few months, it is technically possible to keep the IP's and only change the netmask IF THE ISP PREPARES FOR THIS UP FRONT or you get incredibly lucky - but most likely, unless you let them know your intention and they are agreeable, they would want to assign you a new subnet, which could well be in a different range.

Comment: What if I used another router for the separate IP ranges? First set of 5 usable IP with router #1 and router #2 in case they assign different range for the additional 8 usable IP.

Comment: The thing is that you were talking about a /29 (8 ips = 5 useable) as opposed to a /28 (16 ips = 13 useable),  so 2 x /29's providers only 10 usable IP's, not 13.  A decent router should be able to handle this, but your provider may be loathe to provide you 2 x /29's (and indeed might have issues routing them to you depending on their platform) when a /28 is more customary.    It would be harder to have 2 routers to handle 2 x /29's then a single one handling both.

Comment: From a providers point of view, if they know upfront you might want to convert the /29 to a /28 later, they could provide you half the block, and reserve the other half for you later, then simply change the netmask.  This only works if they allocate a /29 on the appropriate boundary, and the adjacent block is kept free though.

Comment: Because they allow you to order them in packs, 5 usable and 13 usable. Max is 13. So initially I will be assigned a /29 (8 IPs 5 usable) but if I upgrade to a /28 (16 IPs 13 usable) not sure how they going to do it if I'll be put on different range. Now that I've done a bit more research, I think what I need is 1 router per IP, so for 5 usable IP it'll go modem -> switch -> 5 routers? I do want each IP on their on router to separate the network.

Comment: @NoNo No offense, but maybe you need to get someone with some networking qualifications to help you understand the concept of subnetting. You will most likely require a "master router", and then you can hang 5 separate SOHO routers off this if you want to have 5 natted networks behind 5 different IP's.   Depending on your network topography, you might be better off getting a "proper" (not 4/5 port soho router unless you put *WRT on it) or linux based box + managed switch, using VLANs to create a multiport router, effectively making a super router.  I think you are in way over your head though.